# Angular Universal with Route Param when SSR

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-universal

I've got a strange issue with my Angular Universal App (v8.1.1).

I can't see any related current or past issues in the Universal repo.

A simple example of my code:

routes:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':routeParam',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

component:

```
...
export class ChildComponent {

  id: string;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params[ 'routeParam' ]; // get unexpected values eg. favicon.ico
  }

}
```

server.ts:

```
...

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static( join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser') ) );

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req, res });
});
```

The dynamic route (with params) works fine when rendered by the browser, but not when Server Side Rendered.

It timeouts and breaks.

When Server Side Rendered it receives `favicon.ico` and `bg.svg` as the `routeParam` value (as well as the expected string value).

These files are assets served from the domain/assets/.. folder.

So I don't understand how they get to the component route param.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try instead the recommend way to retrieving route params via an observable: https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the express [serve static middleware documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html)

> When a file is not found, instead of sending a 404 response, this module will instead call next() to move on to the next middleware,

I think that for some reason express cannot find the static files `favicon.ico` and `bg.svg`, so it then calls the next middleware, which is handled by the angular app and its routing.

Make sure that the dist\browser folder contains the files you are looking for. If they do, try to check the relative path for these files when they are called from angular

Comment: Makes sense. I will try this today. Would this not happen for the main route though (only the child route has this timeout issue)?

Comment: Worked. Thanks. I was trying to find the error somewhere else.